# Gherkin to json parsing with Java

Tags: parsing, gherkin

I am trying to parse Gherkin feature file to JSOn. I am trying to use the code below and would like to know how to create json file and write into it?

```
   String path = "gherkin path loc"       
   StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();
   JSONFormatter formatter = new JSONFormatter(json);
   Parser parser = new Parser(formatter);
   parser.parse(gherkin, path, 0);

   formatter.done();
   formatter.close()
```